# Unknown class in storyboard when assigning Swift class in Xcode 6 beta 4

Tags: storyboard, uicollectionviewlayout, xcode6

I've started new project in Xcode6 beta 4 and in Swift language. I'm using `UICollectionView` which is added in storyboard and all is connected and works nice with default flow layout. Also I've created Swift subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` class and changed layout in storyboard to custom and typed name of this custom class. The problem is that when I did this and run app I've got message in console: "Unknown class `ClassName` in Interface Builder" and `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not called (because of non-existing layout I think). Is this some bug in this version of Xcode or maybe I forgot about something?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've checked this. I've created the same class but in Objective-C and Storyboard is correctly working with this class. So it looks like a bug. I Added radar for this: 17777332.

Comment: I'm encountering this as well in Beta 4. Let me know if you hear anything.

Comment: You cannot pass exact name of the class but its signature. If you tap button in this field you can find there signature of your swift class with prefix `TF-something` and that's your class. Try it.